# How to run Testcontainers in Containerd without any error (from Kubernetes 1.20)?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, testcontainers, containerd

[Since Kubernetes 1.20](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/12/02/dont-panic-kubernetes-and-docker/), Docker support is deprecated and will be totally removed from 1.24. We use GKE to manage Kubernetes so the upgrade will be done automatically.

As far as I've read, developers should not have been impacted but we made tests in Kubernetes 1.23 to check that all is OK and it seems we have some issues with a microservice using Testcontainers :

```
09:59:44.578 [testcontainers-ryuk] WARN org.testcontainers.utility.ResourceReaper - Can not connect to Ryuk at localhost:49153
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
    at org.testcontainers.utility.ResourceReaper.lambda$null$3(ResourceReaper.java:194)
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.ratelimits.RateLimiter.doWhenReady(RateLimiter.java:27)
    at org.testcontainers.utility.ResourceReaper.lambda$start$4(ResourceReaper.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

This is not reproductible on a Kubernetes 1.19 where Docker is not deprecated nor removed.

We tried to disable Ryuk in `pom.xml` (as indicated for this error in a [Testcontainers issue](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/3609)) but it has no effect :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>verify</goal>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <environmentVariables>
                    <TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED>true</TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED>
                </environmentVariables>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

To reproduce locally, we tried to launch IT with testcontainers in a Minikube with Kubernetes 1.23 and Containerd as container runtime (no docker env):

```
minikube start --kubernetes-version v1.23.0 
--network-plugin=cni 
--enable-default-cni 
--container-runtime=containerd 
--bootstrapper=kubeadm
```

But it leads to this error when launching `mvn -T 2 failsafe:integration-test failsafe:verify` :

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.87 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.ggl.merch.kafka.it.MerchandisingConsumerIT                   
[ERROR] should_consume_merchandising_message_and_process_record  Time elapsed: 0.012 s  <<< ERROR!                                                                                                                 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration                   
        at com.ggl.merch.kafka.it.MerchandisingConsumerIT.<init>(MerchandisingConsumerIT.java:91)
```

Anyone already had the same problem?

Thank you by advance!

Comment: Did you get the exact same error log with `TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED`? If yes, this would indicate, that the `environmentVariables` directive is not working, try setting it outside of Maven.

Comment: Yes, I tried this: TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED=true mvn -T 2 failsafe:integration-test failsafe:verify

But it leads to this error:

org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed

Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.RetryCountExceededException: Retry limit hit with exception

Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Could not create/start container

Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Timed out waiting for container port to open (localhost ports: [49154] should be listening)

Comment: If this stacktrace does not originate from `ResourceReaper`, it is a different error and likely not related to Ryuk after all. Instead, this suggests problems with the networking configuration and Testcontainers in the JVM process not being able to communicate with the mapped ports of the Docker container. 

I'd suggest you create an issue at Testcontainers GitHub. Might be easier to follow up on debugging steps there (such as manually verifying Docker networking works with Docker CLI).

Comment: Please do not edit your title with "SOLVED". You already did the job by self-answering your question. You will be able to self-accept that answer in a few moment.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved** by putting this in our configuration:

```
- name: "TESTCONTAINERS_HOST_OVERRIDE"
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: status.hostIP
```

Following [this doc](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/configuration/):

> **`TESTCONTAINERS_HOST_OVERRIDE`**
>     Docker's host on which ports are exposed.
>     Example: `docker.svc.local`